# C# Winforms. Drawing text accurately centrally within a rectangle

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

What I'm attempting to do is draw a number inside a circle so that it's positioned centrally both vertically and horizontally. I'm drawing both the circle and text string using the same rectangle structure and using center for both horizontal and vertical alignments. But, as you can see from the image where I drew a horizontal line across the white circle, the text is aligning its base line centrally and my eye says it's horizontally aligning slightly to the left.

I've tried fudging by adding string.height/2 to the top of the rectangle to shift it down 1/2 its height but it's still not correct. (I adjust the font size so the number will fit within the box according to the number of digits in the counter)

How can I do this properly please?

```
var rect = new Rectangle(bmpWidth - maxCircleDiameter, bmpHeight - maxCircleDiameter, maxCircleDiameter, maxCircleDiameter);
g.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, rect);

using (var format = NewClassFactory.GetFormat(StringAlignment.Center, StringAlignment.Center, StringTrimming.Character))
  g.DrawString(toDisplay, newFont, Brushes.Black, rect, format);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`TextRenderer.DrawText`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textrenderer.drawtext(v=vs.110).aspx) to draw a text in a rectangle bound, using a color and font and specifying different text format flag:

```
var rect = new Rectangle(10, 10, 32, 32);
e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
e.Graphics.FillEllipse(Brushes.White, rect);
TextRenderer.DrawText(e.Graphics, "100", this.Font, rect, Color.Black,
    TextFormatFlags.HorizontalCenter | TextFormatFlags.VerticalCenter);
```

Comment: Nice. That aligns perfectly except the font itself now looks screwy, smudged as if it's drawn twice at slightly off to the right. I've a breakpoint on my code so I know it's only stepped through once.

Comment: nvm. I added the backcolor option and it's now perfect. Thank you so much Reza :)